# Detecting columns in a document (table) via php - Algorithm

Tags: php, html, algorithm, dom

Given a table like the one below, what would be the best way to detect the two columns separately?

So what I would need the total colspans for the first column.

What is important to remember is that the nr of columns can change.

In the case of this example, the second column starts at "10 euro" (second row). The first section is equal to 2 colspans. The other section is 5 colspans.

Any (abstract) ideas on how to do this?

[image]

Comment: First thing that came to mind is: XY-Cut algorithm ... simplified version of it though ;-) only one cut required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must consider the gaps in between the table cells and mark their positions, like this::

```
0 1 2 3 4     7
0   2 3 4 5 6 7
0 1 2   4 5   7
...
0   2         7
```

Once you have built an array with above information, you iterate over them and mark the common gap locations:

```
0   2         7
```

Since 0 and 7 are both at the edges of your table, you can strip those off. Then you're left with position 2 as the common gap between your rows.

Done :)

Comment: Thanks, I thought of something similar after I posted, this will probably work in 95% of cases and I can find some other solutions for edge cases.

Comment: @Wesley cool! i've used this algorithm successfully on another project that does OCR tracing; you can find the "Recursive XY Cut" algorithm online, but I spared you the read of this rather dry PDF document ;-)

Comment: Oh nice, didn't know this was the XY cut algorithm. I looked it up when you first posted it, but thought it was to cut up an image in separate images (columns). Anyway, thanks!

Comment: This is just the first step of the algorithm; it would continue by "carving" out the areas you have determined in the previous step, change direction (horizontal -> vertical) and recursively apply itself on the remaining areas.